# Why is my Angular FormGroup Valid when a control that is marked as required is empty?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, formgroups

I am trying to setup a basic form validation for a select.

In  my constructor I have the following `FormGroup`

```
this.formSubmission = new FormGroup(
  {
    triggers: new FormControl(['', [ Validators.required]])
  }
)
```

I have a button on the screen to test the validity of the `FormGroup` and it always comes back as valid even when there is nothing selected for "triggers".

When clicked the following code executes:

```
console.log('FormGroup Status: ' + this.formSubmission.status)
```

This will return VALID.

The HTML portion of this can be found here:

```
<div [formGroup]="formSubmission">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Triggers</mat-label>
    <mat-select 
    formControlName="triggers" multiple
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let trigger of triggersList" [value]="trigger.TRIGGER_NAME">{{trigger.TRIGGER_NAME}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the result of ``console.log('FormGroup value: ' + this.formSubmission.value)`` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined triggers wrong.

```
  triggers: new FormControl(['', [ Validators.required]])
```

will result in triggers: array.
First argument is the value, second is the validators, asyncValidators or options

what you probably meant to do is this:

```
triggers: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required])
```